# DDEV accessing wrong .css-file, different home base the productive system

Tags: typo3, ddev, typo3-11.x

I'm working on a downloaded productive TYPO3 homepage (v11.5) and set it up in DDEV.

Now during my work I recognised that the base href for inclusion of user-specified .css-files are different from the productive system.

While in the productive system, the .css-file is correctly loaded from

```
https://mydomain.at/fileadmin/templates/assets/css/mybootstrap2.css?1636470015
```

it is in the DDEV environment requested from

```
https://mydomain.ddev.site/sternwarte-mydomain/fileadmin/templates/assets/css/mybootstrap2.css?1674722424
```

Which obviously added a Typo3 page references (`sternwarte-mydomain/`) to the path, an therefore correctly resulted in an

```
net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

for the GET-operation as this is the wrong location.

Any hints/suggestions where my error could be.

**EDIT:**

Extract of the Typoscript.
[image: Typoscript]

Resulting sourcecode

[image: Sourcecode]

**EDIT 2:**

Site configuration:

[image]

Comment: I can't imagine how this has anything to do with DDEV. It's your code that determines what css files get loaded...

Comment: You may be right. Its most propably not ddev, but in my case it's the combination ddev/typo3. Why I mentioned ddev is as it used to run a local copy of typo3 and also a setting for "Development" when the problem occurs. Which don't occur in the productive system. AND I amjust using it cookbook like, with basically no knowledge of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to set `config.absRefPrefix = /` in TypoScript? Or check the entry point of your site configuration.

Update:
Try to set the link to the CSS file with a slash in front, e.g. file1 = /fileadmin/templates/assets/css/mybootstrap2.css. Or try to set config.baseURL = /.

Comment: config.absRefPrefix = / didn't make any difference. Interestingly a js is delivered correctly, as well as the favicon. 
  I edit the post above to show the TS and resulting sourcecode.

Comment: What does your site configuration look like?

Comment: See EDIT 2 in the question.
They have been generated out of Typo3.

Comment: Try to set the link to the CSS file with a slash in front, e.g. `file1 = /fileadmin/templates/assets/css/mybootstrap2.css`. Or try to set `config.baseURL = /`.

Comment: The preceding `/` was the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Glad that it worked out. I've updated my initial answer. Maybe you can mark it as correct.